# Setting custom colors in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to customize the color scheme in PhpStorm to my liking.  What I would like to do is set a different color for words like 'public', 'private' or 'protected' and the actual word 'function' when inside a class.

However, if I go to Settings->Colors & Fonts->PHP, I can't figure out how to do that.  It seems that all of these words are considered Keywords and therefore have to have the same color.

Is there are a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such functionality is not supported ATM.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22194 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress. So far it's not scheduled for any specific future release .. plus it has only 2 votes.